# Sharepoint 2010 Taxonomy 3rd party replacement?

Tags: taxonomy

I would like to know if a 3rd party professional Taxonomy replacement exists for the default SharePoint 2010 Microsoft implementation?

Comment: I don't know if there are any out there (yet). Why do you ask?

Comment: @Wictor, the standard Taxonomy implementation has some serious short comings. I'm looking for a quick swop out and replace solution.

Comment: We're using it successfully on our site for both profiles and some custom applications for content.  What do you see as short comings?  If its something we have not hit yet it would be nice to know.

Comment: @MichaelF, add a metadata filter to a list, and see if you can filter results accurately. This is one huge shortfall of the current Taxonomy implementation. Check out some of my other questions as well as time goes by. We're calling in MS for a whole lot of gold support with Taxonomy.

Comment: I was hoping to find more 3rd parties information here. Please admin, look at the question and let the man speak! SharePoint doesn't have a well working taxonomy solution which is also one of the reasons they don't call it that, they call it Managed Meta Data.

Comment: @mrsbeata We generally only accept questions that have one specific answer. You could try asking a discussion question on the [SharePoint MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/category/sharepoint/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [MatchPoint for SharePoint](http://www.colygon.com/matchpoint-framework/) (where I am working for).

It comes with it's own metadata management, but also supports the ootb taxomomy stuff.

Comment: Just a warning that spam is not welcome here. It's OK to advertise your product where it answers a question, but you must disclose that you work for the company in the post, and participate elsewhere in the site without advertising.

Comment: I don't want to spam here. But the questioner is explicitly asking for a 3rd party solution. And I do participate, if you check my profile on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: That is a different site on this network and also has similar spam requirements. The rules are clear and documented in more detail [here](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/63/how-should-we-handle-links-to-third-party-products). Please update your posts accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: Really looks like a well polished solution. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

[WAND, Inc](http://blog.wandinc.com/2011/08/managed-metadata-in-sharepoint-2010.html) is one company that provides taxonomies, tags, etc. They provide prebuilt taxonomies (various industries) and other tools for content management - [DataFacet product](http://www.datafacet.com/General.aspx).
CAVEAT: I do not work for the above company but have examined one of their products and found it satisfactory.